# Bootstrap 4 - Toggle Collapse/Show Only Shows

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

This is driving me mad.

I simply want to have a button to show and hide a DIV in Bootstrap4,  whenever I toggle the class="collapse" the div shows but will not collapse.

On page load the div is collapsed,  button only works once and watching the developer view in Chrome whenever the button is clicked it switches from 'collapsing' to collapse.show again? Click it again, and it populates with collapse.show every time.

*JQuery is in the header.*

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#site- 
details">Collapsible</button>

<div class = "collapse" id="site-details">
<div class="container" id="container-dash1">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
   <div class="card-header">.....etc
```

Any help appreciated, this is driving me nuts.  Tested on several devices/browsers.

Comment: Does setting `type="button"` on `button` help? Any errors in console?

Comment: No, I've tired it with a button and a link, and the behaviour is exactly the same.

I am doing something wrong here and it's very frustrating!

Answer (score 3):

Solved,  two instances of Bootstrap/JQuery in the page.

Used a header/content set-up, both have BS/JQ include and clearly they were having an argument!

Comment: for me as well there was already a bootstrap in the packaged js, why downvote this answere???

Comment: Indeed, if there are two instances, it will not toggle.
I spent two days to figure out why until i find this answer. 
I am using bootstrap 5 in react
Thanks.